# html5 boilerplate custom template

Tags: html5boilerplate

Good evening, I'm using the html5 boilerplate for the first time. After I downloaded the zip and I have two questions. First is: Can I delete the files that doesn't necessary for my website?. The second is: The License file should be in the project?

Thanks,

Alessandro

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can delete anything you're not using. We've always promoted ourselves as being "delete key friendly."  It's meant to be a foundation for other work.